# How to associate a user in a Rails nested model form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-attributes

Given the typical nested model example from Railscasts:

http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1

How would you associate the answers to a user?

Rephrased, if you're building a model through another model, how would you associate a user for every child element created?

Rephrased yet again with another example:

If I had Albums and Pictures and I created many Pictures at once through the Album's controller associating it to that Album, how would I associate every Picture in that same update_attributes call or whatever the most idiomatic way for Rails is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using the following to make it work:

```
params[:exercise][:log_entries_attributes].each do |value|
  value[1].merge!(:user_id => current_user.id)
end
```

Is there a more Rails or Ruby appropriate version of handling this?